# Ag-grid cellValueChanged style update

Tags: typescript, ag-grid-angular

I use Ag Grid to display an editable table and I have a default style applied to the cells. I want to update the cell style upon user modification. 
So I use the cellValueChanged event and try to update the style of the modified cell.

You can see in the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-drzrme) that whenever I do a modification, the cellStyle is updated but for the entire column so the behaviour is:

1. Modification of a cell
2. cellStyle applied to the column
3. Whenever you click in a cell the new style is applied (modification or not)

What I want to do is get the modified cell and apply the style to the cell itself. Is that possible with Ag Grid?

Comment: cell color is changing to red from the stackblitz

Comment: are you trying to change cell background?